# Interpreting var.test results in R

Tags: r

I am trying to learn F test and on performing the inbuilt var.test() in R, I obtained the following result     var.test(gardenB,gardenC)

```
F test to compare two variances

data:  gardenB and gardenC
F = 0.09375, num df = 9, denom df = 9, p-value = 0.001624
alternative hypothesis: true ratio of variances is not equal to 1
95 percent confidence interval:
0.02328617 0.37743695
sample estimates:
ratio of variances 
           0.09375
```

I understand that based on the p-value, I should reject the Null hypothesis.
However, I am unable to understand the meaning conveyed by the 95 percent confidence interval?

I tried reading through the explanation provided for the queries:
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31454/how-to-interpret-the-confidence-interval-of-a-variance-f-test-using-r

But am still able to understand the meaning conveyed in the confidence interval. Any help would be really appreciated?

Comment: Questions about statistical methods and model interpretations are off topic for Stack Overflow (which is just for programming questions). Statistical questions belong on [stats.se].

Comment: Sure .. Will post in Cross-Validated. Thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, I know this is an old post but it showed up as the second result on google so I will try to answer the question still.

**The confidence interval is for the RATIO of the two variances.**

For example, if the variances are equal ie. `var1 = var2`, the ratio would be `var1/var2` which is 1.

`var.test()` is usually used to test if the variances are equal. If 1 is not in the 95% confidence interval, it is safe to assume that the variances are not equal and thus, reject the hypothesis.